# EditText Integer Comparing

Tags: android, integer, android-edittext, compare

I am encountering problems when comparing input integer from EditText. I cant find what is wrong with it. Please help me. Here is the code below.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.problem2);
        textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.probText);
        Button ans3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);



        ans3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String probString = textIn.getText().toString();
                Integer probInt = Integer.parseInt(probString);
                Integer prob = 31;
                if (probInt.equals(prob)) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(answer3.this,"CORRECT!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.sample.androidsample.ANSWER4")    );

                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(answer3.this,"Wrong answer! Try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried (probInt == prob) ?

Comment: can yo put Log.i("@@@", probString); after String probString = textIn.getText().toString(); and check what is the output in logcat?

Comment: tried  (probInt == prob) it always returns the else statements

Comment: Always sanitize your input, using a `Pattern` to weed out bad inputs first, then knowing that the Pattern *matched*, then it can be safely parsed as an `Integer`.

Comment: Try trimming it. String probString = textIn.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: trim() didnt solved it. is there any other alternative way of an EditText integer comparison?

Comment: Try print the probInt first to manually check it's value.

Comment: Look, to save us hours of trying to guess, would you just use the `Log.d("marcc abaya", "probString = " + probString)` and tell us what is the value of `probString`. @Hesam asked you explicitly 11 hours ago, and @MarchellImanuel as well - 10 hours ago... so far we've seen nothing - -1 from me for poor cooperation with us and playing the guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Integer probInt = Integer.parseInt(probString);
            Integer prob = 31;
            //changed from equals() to ==
            if (probInt == prob)) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(answer3.this,"CORRECT!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.sample.androidsample.ANSWER4")    );

            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(answer3.this,"Wrong answer! Try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
```

From what I understand `equals` is for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Integer probInt = Integer.parseInt(probString);` you can use `Integer probInt = Integer.valueOf(probString);` but i'm not sure this is the problem. and also instead of `probInt.equals(prob)`  you can use `probInt.equalIgnoreCase(prob)`.

Comment: already tried it. still same problem. im wondering why is it not comparing right..

Comment: I think you need to see what is the content of probInt in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong line.

```
Integer prob = 31;
```

Here Integer is a class, so you will have to instantiate it like below.

```
Integer prob = new Integer(31);
```

or 
you could just use

```
int prob =31;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 Integer probInt = Integer.parseInt(probString);
 Integer prob = 31;
 if (probInt.equals(prob)) {
 } else {
 }
```

use

```
int probInt = (int) Integer.parseInt(probString);
int prob = 31;
if (probInt == prob) {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing, It Will Work

```
Integer probInt = Integer.parseInt(probString);
        Integer prob = 31;
        //changed from equals() to ==
        if (probInt.intValue() == prob.intValue()) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(answer3.this,"CORRECT!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            startActivity(new Intent("com.sample.androidsample.ANSWER4")    );

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(answer3.this,"Wrong answer! Try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Comment: yeah now try it, i missed a )

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of sanitizing the input. Exception handling omitted for brevity.

```
private Pattern patternNum = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{1,5})$", 
                               Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);

// Wrap it in a try/catch for PatternSyntaxException!
private boolean validateNum(String inputNum){
    return patternNum.matcher(inputNum);
}
```

Then assuming the `validateNum` routine returns true, meaning it matches at least 5 digits, then saying this:

```
if (validateNum(probString)){
   int probInt = Integer.parseInt(probString);
   if (probInt == prob){
      // Success
   }else{
      // Failure
   }
}else{
   // Whoops! Bad input caught!
}
```

Comment: already tried it. input is correct but mismatch comparison. always returns the failure

Comment: @marcc abaya: failure in what? be more specific?